# asp.net c# prevent firing selectedindexchanged event while changing index from serverside code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dropdownlist controls on the same aspx page as

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlM" runat="server" Width="123px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlM_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlC" runat="server" Width="123px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlC_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

the C# code for OnSelectedIndexChanged of both are as below :

```
protected void ddlC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ddlM.SelectedIndex = 0;
   ViewState["ddlC"] = true;
   ViewState["ddlM"] = false;                 
   BindPGrid();            
}

protected void ddlM_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ddlC.SelectedIndex = 0;                
   ViewState["ddlC"] = false;
   ViewState["ddlM"] = true; 
   BindPGrid();
}
```

both are populated by database record items using some server-side code. Now, OnSelectedIndexChanged event of "ddlM" I want to make selected the first index of "ddlC" but WITHOUT firing the event ddlC_SelectedIndexChanged. And same for "ddlC" as OnSelectedIndexChanged event of "ddlC" I want to make selected the first index of "ddlM" but WITHOUT firing the event ddlM_SelectedIndexChanged. Right not it fires the event. How can I do prevent it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that you do not want to fire the corresponding event because it would then reset the original one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you can remove and re-add the SelectedIndexChanged event handler from the control

```
 ddlM.SelectedIndexChanged -= ddlM_SelectedIndexChanged;

 ddlM.SelectedIndex = 0;
 ViewState["ddlC"] = false;
 ViewState["ddlM"] = true; 
 BindPGrid();

 ddlM.SelectedIndexChanged += ddlM_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Then you don't have to mess with global flags

Answer (score 3):

In such cases we create a global `bool` flag and sets its value to `true` before changing `SelectedIndexChanged`. And in the other Control's `SelectedIndexChanged` check its value if its true. If true we return it outside the event. And change flag value again when outside. Make sure to always change flag value back to false or else it would never fire if that event is generated by same control.

```
boool flag = false;

protected void ddlC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   flag = true;
   ddlM.SelectedIndex = 0;
   flag = false;
   ViewState["ddlC"] = true;
   ViewState["ddlM"] = false;                 
   BindPGrid();            
}

protected void ddlM_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(flag)
       return;

   ddlC.SelectedIndex = 0;                
   ViewState["ddlC"] = false;
   ViewState["ddlM"] = true; 
   BindPGrid();
}
```

or you can remove the event handler like

```
protected void ddlC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ddlM.SelectedIndexChanged -= ddlM_SelectedIndexChanged;
   ddlM.SelectedIndex = 0;
   ddlM.SelectedIndexChanged += ddlM_SelectedIndexChanged;
   ViewState["ddlC"] = true;
   ViewState["ddlM"] = false;                 
   BindPGrid();            
}
```

Comment: Curious why this is getting upvotes? He just copied my answer on to the end of his, and more importantly his syntax is wrong, this won't even compile.

Comment: How does your global bool work when the index of ddlM is changed first?